# Wake up AppleTV over HTTP

Tags: reverse-engineering, apple-tv

I'd like to wake up my AppleTV when I turn on my projector and lower the screen - this happens using a Broadlink RM Pro hub, Alexa and a Raspberry Pi.

Ideally I'd just like to issue something like http://192.168.86.30:3689/wakeup

I have looked at [the great contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37042605/4204433) which links some Python code to login, control, and logout of the AppleTV on pastebin.com

Does anybody have experience with this code - I think I have login and logout working (with 200 and 204 response codes), but I cannot seem to get other commands to work (403 responses for all).